# Why does switch execute (int type)cases that aren't matched?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am a little puzzled why all cases are executed here, even the ones that aren't matched if I remove the break statement here:

```
int i = 0;
    switch ( i ) {
        case 0: System.out.print (i) ;
        case 1: System.out.print (i) ;
        case 2: System.out.print (i) ;
        case 3: System.out.print (i) ;
        default : System.out.print (i) ;
    }
```

This code prints out 5 times the value i. 
If I were to add a break after case 0, it just prints the value out once.

Reading the documentation and the function description in some books, i had expected it to only print the matching case.

Is this because it's somehow enumerated?
I'm sorry I couldn't find a much better explanation and I've searched extensively, so I figured it has been asked before and I am no good at searching, or it's too basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java `switch` statements, once it matches a `case`, all the `case` clauses after the matching clause are executed sequentially. This fall-through is the expected behavior. If you need to stop this, then `break` at each `case` so that, once a `case` is matched, it will execute only that `case` and then breaks from the `switch` block.

If your input does not match any of the `case` blocks, the `default` case is executed.

This is from the official javadoc

> The break statements are necessary because without them, statements in switch blocks fall through: All statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered.

Try the code with different `i` values and you'll see it for yourself how the `switch` behaves.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, I did it with different i and reading just the line above from the official docs I' had expected the cases to run through 'til the end and not execute. So I was very confused. Your explanation has made it much more clear to what is meant. Thank you!

Comment: @Olli: I can only suggest that you use a decent IDE that would give you a warning ("switch case falls through" or something like that). It helps a lot to spot such things.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have eclipse and intellij, unfortunately it hasn't shown up in either.

Answer (score 3):

You must enter a `break` command after each read, in order to exit the `switch` !

```
int i = 0;
    switch ( i ) {
        case 0: System.out.print (i) ;
        break ;
        case 1: System.out.print (i) ;
        break ;
        case 2: System.out.print (i) ;
        break ;
        case 3: System.out.print (i) ;
        break ;
        default : System.out.print (i) ;
       break ;
    }
```

The `switch` enter to where the condition is true , After that, it executes all the lines of code that comes after . Witout `break` it will not exit and And run the following code lines after.

Comment: Hi, thank you. As mentioned (probably not clear enough by me), I have removed the break statements on purpose above to learn what would happen.
According to a textbook and what I read in the docs. I expected the switch statement to check all cases after the matching case, but I thought it wouldn't execute the code next to it. edit: spelling

Comment: The answer is ok but only part that troubles me is the last statement which says "Witout break it will not exit the curly braces: {}". Remember its not a loop but a conditional statement

Comment: You're right, I edited this post, thanks for the feedback, if you can change your vote I'd be happy!